# Emacs Rmail Gmail - No Mail

Tags: email, emacs, osx-yosemite

I am trying to setup Rmail to read my Gmail account.

I have tried following the instructions on emacswiki:

```
 (setenv "MAILHOST" "pop3server")
 (setq rmail-primary-inbox-list '("po:username")
       rmail-pop-password-required t)
```

and the ones on the info page http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Remote-Mailboxes.html

```
 (setq rmail-primary-inbox-list '("pop://email:password@gmail.com"))
```

But both cases behave the same. When I enter Rmail (M-x Rmail), the minibuffer shows

> Getting mail from the remote server...

For 30 seconds - 1 min, after which it simply says:

> No Mail